# Create React Native App Command Not Found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I am trying to create a react native app using `create-react-native-app`. I have npm install.

I have install create react native by adding the following command to my terminal (on mac).

```
sudo npm install -g create-react-native-app
```

When I try and create a create react native app by running the following command I get told that the command is not found.

> create-react-native-app myNativeApp
>
> bash: create-react-native-app: command not found

Is there any way I can fix this or am I doing something wrong? I am new to create react native app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running wrong command :

To install react native run :

> npm install -g react-native-cli

And then for creating project run :

> react-native init AwesomeProject

[Here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.60/getting-started) is documentation.

Answer (score 2):

At moment [create-react-native-app](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app) is merged with [Expo](https://expo.io/)

To install expo see [doc](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/installation/)

`npm install -g expo-cli`

Usage: `expo [options] [command]`

---

Update:

Try:
`npm config set prefix /usr/local`
And then reinstall react.
`npm install -g create-react-app`
Run
`create-react-app my-app`

Comment: sadly this didn't help

Comment: you use homebrew ?

Comment: I think It should be npm install -g create-react-native-app. That worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`npx` CLI](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup).

From those docs:

> React Native has a built-in command line interface, which you can use to generate a new project. You can access it without installing anything globally using `npx`, which ships with Node.js.

For example:

```
npx react-native init myNativeApp
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to be more substantive, it doesn't satisfy the Stack Overflow standards for an answer as it is now. It might be deleted otherwise, as it is flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.

Answer (score 1):

Try: npm config set prefix /usr/local And then reinstall react. npm install -g create-react-app Run create-react-app my-app

This works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Follow this instruction

1.react-native init Demo Go to that folder,

2.cd Demo

run the command to start package, make sure you started the emulator.

3.react-native start

4.react-native run-android ( For Android Devices)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the command and even I got the same error, so I have used

```
npx create-react-native-app my_first_app
```

this has worked for me!

you can even use

```
sudo npm install expo-cli --global
```

and then use

```
expo init rn-first-app
```

Answer (score 0):

Install updated NPM

Check path variable in your system(Windows)
it should be `OsDrive:\Program Files\nodejs\`

then,

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

now try,

```
npx create-react-app <projectname>
cd <projectdirectory>
npm start
```